How to plot an equation in Metapost?
Sometime ago I found this code on tex SE site:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->]( 0,0) -- (4,0);
    \draw [->]( 0,0) -- (0,4);
    \draw [->,red]( 0,0) -- (400:4);
    \draw[->,domain=0:400,variable=\t,samples=200,>=latex]
    plot ({(\t+400)*cos(\t)/(400)},
    {(\t+400)*sin(\t)/(400)}) node[right=.5cm] {$400^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}

I want to convert this to Metapost. I know only basics of Metapost so any help would be useful.
If I see https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots the I can understand following example:
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
  \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);

  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};

  \draw[color=red]    plot (\x,\x)             node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
  % \x r means to convert '\x' from degrees to _r_adians:
  \draw[color=blue]   plot (\x,{sin(\x r)})    node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
  \draw[color=orange] plot (\x,{0.05*exp(\x)}) node[right] {$f(x) = \frac{1}{20} \mathrm e^x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

but I do not understand:
\tikz \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3.141:3.141,smooth,variable=\t]
  plot ({\t*sin(\t r)},{\t*cos(\t r)});

So essentially my problem is understanding the line \draw[->,domain=0:400,variable=\t,samples=200,>=latex] plot ({(\t+400)*cos(\t)/(400)}, {(\t+400)*sin(\t)/(400)}) node[right=.5cm] {$400^\circ$};

Here is a slightly more idiomatic translation of the TikZ original to MP.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}

numeric u; u = 1cm;

path xx, yy, vector;
xx = origin -- (4u, 0);
yy = xx rotated 90;
vector = xx rotated 400;

path spiral;
numeric s; s = 40;
spiral = (1, 0) for t=s step s until 400: .. (1 + t / 400) * dir t endfor;
spiral := spiral scaled u;

beginfig(1);
  drawarrow xx;
  drawarrow yy;
  drawarrow vector withcolor red;
  drawarrow spiral;
  label.rt("$400^\circ$", point infinity of spiral shifted 10 right);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

There is a lot to be said for naming the parts of your diagram with appropriate variable names.  Compile the above with lualatex to get this:

Notes
Here are some more detailed notes comparing the TikZ original to my MP version.
Axes and the angle marker
In the original you have
\draw [->]( 0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw [->]( 0,0) -- (0,4);
\draw [->,red]( 0,0) -- (400:4);

which draws the x-axis and y-axis and a red angle vector.
In MP I have separated defining the paths from drawing them.
This technique often leads to simpler code that's easier to follow.
The default unit is different too -- in TikZ the default is 1cm, but in MP the default is 1bp, that is one PostScript point, defined as 72bp == 1in == 2.54cm.
So at the simplest, you write
drawarrow (0, 0) -- (113, 0);
drawarrow (0, 0) -- (0, 113);
drawarrow (0, 0) -- (113, 0) rotated 400 withcolor red;

as a direct "translation", but I think it is clearer to define the paths as variables and write:
path xx, yy, vector;
xx = origin -- (4cm, 0);
yy = xx rotated 90;
vector = xx rotated 400;
...
drawarrow xx;
drawarrow yy;
drawarrow vector withcolor red;

Notice also that we can reuse xx instead of repeating the 4cm.
The TikZ polar coordinate notation (400:4) is neat.  In MP you have to write 4cm * right rotated 400.  But plain MP provides dir as a shortcut for right rotated, so you can write 4cm * dir 400 or even 113 dir 400 if you use the default units.
Spiral
TikZ uses the plot function to create a function line like this:
 \draw[->,domain=0:400,variable=\t,samples=200,>=latex] 
   plot ({(\t+400)*cos(\t)/(400)}, {(\t+400)*sin(\t)/(400)}) 
   node[right=.5cm] {$400^\circ$};

The equivalent in MP is an inline loop.  Again we can separate defining the path and drawing it, so just define the path first using a loop with a variable.  We wan't domain=0:400, variable=\t and samples=200, so our loop can be for t=0 step 2 until 400:.  However we can't start or end a <path> with a .. connector, so we need to put the first point outside the loop.  So assuming we have defined our function as f(expr x) = ... to return a <pair>, we can write:
 path spiral;
 spiral = f(0) for t=2 step 2 until 400: .. f(t) endfor;

The function in the original is ({(\t+400)*cos(\t)/(400)}, {(\t+400)*sin(\t)/(400)}) which translates directly to MP as
 ((t + 400) * cosd(t) / 400, (t + 400) * sind(t) / 400)

but we can simplify that a bit to
 ((1 + t / 400) * cosd(t), (1 + t / 400) * sind(t))

or better still
 (1 + t / 400) * (cosd(t), sind(t))

which can be shortened to
 (1 + t / 400) * dir t

so you can define your function as
 vardef f(expr t) = (1 + t / 400) * dir t enddef;

In my version above, I wrote this function inline instead of defining it separately, and I reduced the number of samples from 200 to 10 by increasing the step size, so I ended up with:
path spiral;
numeric s; s = 40;
spiral = (1, 0) for t=s step s until 400: .. (1 + t / 400) * dir t endfor;
spiral := spiral scaled u;

Not forgetting at the end to scale the spiral to my chosen unit.

I figured that it is a parametric equation and then I could convert it to Metapost as below:
vardef f(expr t) = (t + 400) * cosd t/400 enddef;
vardef g(expr t) = (t + 400) * sind t/400 enddef;

u = 2mm;
path curve;
curve = ((f(0), g(0)) for t =  1 upto 400: .. (f(t), g(t)) endfor) scaled u;
drawarrow curve scaled u;


You probably don't need to apply scaled u twice... either apply it to the curve when you define it, or apply it when you draw it.

Thank you. I will change it.
